# How to reduce the size of an ASCII text art picture

Tags: html, text, ascii, symbols

I have an ASCII text art image in large size on an html page, but i am not not able to reduce the size of it on an html page.

It look like this:

`__________¶¶_¶¶__¶¶_¶¶_
_________¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶¶ 
_____¶¶¶¶¶____________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶_______________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶__________________¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶____________________¶¶¶
___¶¶______________________¶¶¶ 
___¶________________________¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶_____¶¶¶______¶¶________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶_____¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶ 
__¶____¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶ 
__¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶__¶¶¶__________¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶¶____________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶_______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶`

Comment: I show you how in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Text, so it's influenced by the font, or more directly the `font-size`

See example [CodePen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwRwar), or the example I included below by hitting the "Run Code Snippet" button. Anything you can do to `font` you can do to your ascii design.

```css
pre {display: inline-block}
pre#normal {font-size: 100%}
pre#smaller {font-size: 50%}
pre#smallest {font-size: 20%}
```

```html
<pre id="normal">
__________¶¶_¶¶__¶¶_¶¶_
_________¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶¶ 
_____¶¶¶¶¶____________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶_______________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶__________________¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶____________________¶¶¶
___¶¶______________________¶¶¶ 
___¶________________________¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶_____¶¶¶______¶¶________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶_____¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶ 
__¶____¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶ 
__¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶__¶¶¶__________¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶¶____________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶_______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
</pre>
<pre id="smaller">
__________¶¶_¶¶__¶¶_¶¶_
_________¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶¶ 
_____¶¶¶¶¶____________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶_______________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶__________________¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶____________________¶¶¶
___¶¶______________________¶¶¶ 
___¶________________________¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶_____¶¶¶______¶¶________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶_____¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶ 
__¶____¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶ 
__¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶__¶¶¶__________¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶¶____________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶_______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
</pre>
<pre id="smallest">
__________¶¶_¶¶__¶¶_¶¶_
_________¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶_¶¶¶ 
_____¶¶¶¶¶____________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶_______________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶__________________¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶____________________¶¶¶
___¶¶______________________¶¶¶ 
___¶________________________¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶_____¶¶¶______¶¶________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶_____¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶ 
__¶____¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶____¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶ 
__¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶__¶¶¶__________¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶ 
___¶¶____________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶_______¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶_____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
____¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ ¶¶¶¶¶ 
__¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___¶¶¶¶¶¶¶_________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶ 
___________________¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶¶
</pre>
```